# HTTP Public Key Pinning (HPKP) without Openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, base64, ssl-certificate, sha

I am planning to generate following pin-sha256 :

```
Public-Key-Pins: 
  pin-sha256="cUPcTAZWKaASuYWhhneDttWpY3oBAkE3h2+soZS7sWs="; 
  pin-sha256="M8HztCzM3elUxkcjR2S5P4hhyBNf6lHkmjAHKhpGPWE="; 
  max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains; 
  report-uri="https://www.example.org/hpkp-report"
```

So that i can keep in IIS for security reasons as below:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Public-Key-Pins" value="pin-sha256=&quot;base64+primary==&quot;; pin-sha256=&quot;base64+backup==&quot;; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

  ...
</system.webServ
```

But my server lacks open ssl and take long time to install because of process issues.

Could you please let me know is there any alternative without these openssl that i can generate pins?

[See this link for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Public_Key_Pinning)

***These are the pin generation commands, i need to do this without openssl , is it possible?***

```
openssl rsa -in my-rsa-key-file.key -outform der -pubout | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the openssl command chain above converted into openssl API calls that output the base64 result to the screen.

The main calls are

- [PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey.html) to read in the private key in PEM format.
- [i2d_RSA_PUBKEY_bio](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/i2d_RSA_PUBKEY_bio.html) to convert the RSA public key into DER format
- [EVP_Digest](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_DigestInit.html) to create the SHA256 digest (hidden behind the [BIO_f_md](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_f_md.html) BIO usage)
- [BIO_f_base64](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_f_base64.html) BIO usage to convert the digest into base64 format

There are lots of ways to do the same job using variations of the above OPENSSL API's depending on your situation.

Below is a C++ usage of the OpenSSL C API.  You can easily strip the C++ bits if required.

```
template<typename T, typename D>
std::unique_ptr<T, D> make_handle(T* handle, D deleter)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, D>{handle, deleter};
}

bool load_rsa_private_key_and_base64_sha256_hash_public_key()
{
    // load rsa private key in PEM format
    auto bio = make_handle(BIO_new_file("privatekey.pem", "rb"), BIO_free);
    if(!bio) return false;
    auto const key = make_handle(PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio.get(), nullptr, nullptr, (void*)("password")), EVP_PKEY_free);
    bio.reset();

    if(!key) return false;

    // extract private key from loaded certificate
    auto const rsa = EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA(key.get());
    if (!rsa) return false;

    // setup sha256 bio chain
    auto const bmd = make_handle(BIO_new(BIO_f_md()), BIO_free);
    if(!bmd) return false;
    if (!BIO_set_md(bmd.get(), EVP_sha256())) return false;

    auto const null_bio = make_handle(BIO_new(BIO_s_null()), BIO_free);
    auto in = BIO_push(bmd.get(), null_bio.get());

    // write RSA Public Key into DER format to the SHA256 digest BIO chain
    i2d_RSA_PUBKEY_bio(in, rsa);

    // extract the SHA256 digest
    auto mdtmp = BIO_find_type(in, BIO_TYPE_MD);
    if (!mdtmp) return false;
    std::array<char, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE> buffer;
    auto const length = BIO_gets(mdtmp, buffer.data(), buffer.size());

    if(length <= 0)  return false;

    // convert the digest to base64 and output to the stdio
    auto const b64 = make_handle(BIO_new(BIO_f_base64()), BIO_free);
    auto const bio_out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    auto out = BIO_push(b64.get(), bio_out);

    BIO_write(out, buffer.data(), length);
    BIO_flush(out);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: is there any way we can generate pin using cmd? instead of code and openssl

Comment: I sounds like you are asking the question is the wrong place.  This is a programing answer web site...  I'm sure there are other programs that can do what you want but I'm not sure you are going to get an answer here.  It would also help to know what platform you need to generate this on?  At least openssl is ported to pretty much all platforms, most other programs will be specific some platforms.